# Errors in a Simple Ruby Program

Tags: ruby, syntax-error

I've been having some trouble with this code. When I run it, it tells me:

> unexpected $end, expecting }

Here's the code:

```
puts "You have been contacted, and pooled into a secret orginization. Please select your mode."
puts "Double Agent"
puts "Spy"
Mode_Split = gets.chomp
# This is the turning point.
if Mode_Split = "Double Agent"
puts "Your job is to return data points from the FXR (Free Xutopian Republic) to the SU (Shared Union)."
Agency_Members = [["HEAD OF AGENCY", "Robin Woods" "AKA: Dexter"],["HIGHER UPS", "Bryan Silk", "AKA: Silk Road", "Voilet Blue", "AKA: Hydraog"],["AGENTS","Alex Cooper", "Matt Syon", "Jack Cumberland" "Mike Schmidt", "Frits Fitsgerald"],["SUSPECTED DOUBLE AGENTS", "Jack Cumberland"]]
Agency_Members.each { |X| puts Agency_Members }
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things wrong that should be addressed:

In answer to your question, you are missing your 'end' for 'if'

`if <condition>
   stuff in here
end`

You also need to change the capital 'X' to lowercase. Upper case variables denote a constant, so a capital "X" can't be use as a block index.

Ruby convention is to use lower case/snake case for variable names, so `Mode_Split` and `Agency_members` should be `mode_split` and `agency_members`

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're missing an `end` after the `if` statement. I'm not sure where you're trying to end that statement, but you need to do something like:

```
if Mode_Split = "Double Agent" 
  puts "Your job is to return data points from the FXR (Free Xutopian Republic) to the SU (Shared Union)."
  Agency_Members = [["HEAD OF AGENCY", "Robin Woods" "AKA: Dexter"],["HIGHER UPS", "Bryan Silk", "AKA: Silk Road", "Voilet Blue", "AKA: Hydraog"],["AGENTS","Alex Cooper", "Matt Syon", "Jack Cumberland" "Mike Schmidt", "Frits Fitsgerald"],["SUSPECTED DOUBLE AGENTS", "Jack Cumberland"]]
  Agency_Members.each { |X| puts Agency_Members }
end
```